# How to Find Matching Record Using Left Join in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, left-join

I currently have two tables with relationships between the tables: a users table and a comments table.

What I am trying to do is select user.username where comments.location has the same value as user.location. How do I get the currently logged in users comment?

I've tried using Auth::id() within the leftJoin however the error message received is query undefined and also the below statement.

```
$query = DB::table('recommendation')
    ->select('users.username')
    ->leftJoin('users','recommendation.location', '=', 'users.location')  
    ->leftJoin('users','recommendation.user_id', '=' ,  Auth::id())
    ->get();
```

The below statement prints all usernames which have the same location.

```
$query = DB::table('comments')
    ->select('users.username')
    ->leftJoin('users','comments.location', '=', 'users.location')  
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need a `WHERE` clause here:

```
$query = DB::table('recommendation')
   ->select('users.username')
   ->leftJoin('users','recommendation.location', '=', 'users.location')
   ->where('users.user_id', '=', Auth::id())
   ->get();
```

Comment: this looks like it will make `users.user_id = 1` in the WHERE clause making this query to return the results like a INNER JOIN instead?

Comment: @RaymondNijland This answer is speculative, and yes maybe the OP doesn't even need left join here.

Comment: "maybe the OP doesn't even need left join here." very true indeed.

Comment: The genesis of my answer is that the OP appears to be applying a second join when in fact a where clause restriction seems more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TimBiegeleisen , I shall have a go at your solution now.